# Microsoft graph api- Planner permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am building an app where anybody in my organization can create planner task under a specified plan.

I am using Azure AD v2 endpoints for getting access token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

And using that access token to make POST request to following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks
```

I have registered my App on: `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com`
And given necessary delegated and application permissions **EDIT:** ie **Group.ReadWrite.All**
(along with many others)

I am(having admin rights) able to create planner tasks using the API calls but no one else in the organization can. User gets this error message:

```
Need admin approval
Planner Task App

Planner Task App needs permission to access resources in your organization that 
only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this 
app before you can use it.
```

I know that this user account has required permissions (because when using graph explorer api calls with same account, it works) so the problem lies in App permissions. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT:
Bearer token for Admin (where app successfully creates a planner task):

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFCSGg0a21TX2FLVDVYcmp6eFJBdEh6MmtUREpfbzduN3lETXJvVzhkUjR1YWZVZ050OEctbmhuNm5HalpvN1p5SDNqNEl0a3E5N3lFX091cEI2eEdITVVpcWpfeFVkdkFWdmx2SVgtV3FlSmlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiRlNpbXVGckZOb0Mwc0pYR212MTNuTlpjZURjIiwia2lkIjoiRlNpbXVGckZOb0Mwc0pYR212MTNuTlpjZURjIn0.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.T50Ae8vFtdobi4GFHL4o-rqU9sbNYqhhV0KRcA7HYzUI-4M4Latma8kJ7ssqx4djdQigPnjJTCVOg9oFBXE_iSWRPbZbRGbfuvwj9iPePCtzCERZwWn0bHOltk0o0LFWW1UoplUsMJJgxoZyeMlruWBxOIQXOQxRnHlnmMLzU-Nwr2Ex87hAMnFPBN7uD9x7WIJtc3vO-sIecKLmwKgchfbI8vIXMOgs1DsVByWBljHSN-DJ9FwxklS_r-Hco9x6g5SPJ_gXfANL8KXXK51D1Xnc7TKd3IebnjermycCKw5t-ViNPlX0r-og4iKsT2oo_k1UTi5-TO2mMIKPXMjirQ
```

Even after Admin has given consent to the app using (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=my-app-id&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp), non-admin user gets this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you are adding planner task not just reading data, you have to grant permission `Group.ReadWrite.All` accordingly. Please check the permission and confirm about this.

ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/planner_post_tasks

Comment: Yes, I did add Group.ReadWrite.All, still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `Group.ReadWrite.All` you need the consent of a tenant Admin. To obtain this you need to have an Admin on the tenant execute the Admin Consent process.

I have a walkthrough that might help you here:

1. [v2 Endpoint & Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-user-vs-admin/) (explains the various consent workflows involved)
2. [v2 Endpoint & Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) (explains how to obtain Admin Consent)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I already have admins' (tenant & global admins) consents for a bunch of permissions for this app. The error clearly states "Application Permission" issue but I don't understand why because app has all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Your app needs Admin Consent. When you execute Admin Consent it consents to a fixed set of scopes for a single App ID. If you change your scopes _or_ your App ID then you need to re-consent the application.

Comment: But I don't think I changed any scope. Am I missing something here.
P.S: I checked the links you provided got more insight on permissions. Thanks

Comment: If you can add a failing bearer token to your question, it can be used to confirm that this is the case.

Comment: Well that's what the issue is, non-admin users can't go beyond the point where app asks for admin consent, but  I have edited question with admin bearer token if that gives any clue to what am I doing wrong.

Comment: If you're getting that screen, it's telling you that you're requesting scopes that have no received Admin Consent yet. I was able to execute the Admin Consent for your app against a test tenant and it was correctly requesting `Group.ReadWrite.All`. What are you getting for a result from the Admin Consent?

Comment: When I do the admin consent, it gives me a list of permissions including Group.ReadWrite.All and when I accept that in url it gives me "admin_consent=true" and redirects to the uri that is defined in the app which is localhost/myapp/oauth this uri endpoint looks for access token and redirects accordingly. And again when I try creating task using non-admin user I get that "App permission screen"

Comment: Do you see the same behavior regardless of the user? I'm wondering if there may be something specific with the AAD configuration or the account itself. Also, are you able to authenticate the user with basic scopes (i.e. `User.Read`)?

Comment: My app has https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.ReadWrite.All with admin consent but when I try to create a planner with it:

    graphClient.Planner.Plans.Request().AddAsync(plannerPlan); 

I get Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

I am trying to add a planner tab to a team channel
What else needs to be done?